# Android Studio error after ./studio.sh

Tags: linux, android-studio

After `./studio.sh` in a terminal I get this error "tools.jar is not in android studio classpath Please ensure `JAVA_HOME` points to JDK rather than JRE".

I Google it and this is what everybody says: 
"you need to set your environment variable to JDK path instead of JRE"

I try this two commands

```
export PATH=${JDK_HOME}:/etc/java-7-openjdk

export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}:/etc/java-7-openjdk
```

And execute again `./studio.sh` and I get the same error

My OS is `Linux Mint 14`

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I solved the problem combining Jerome's and Jarod's answer:

1. Install JDK -- `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`
2. Environment Variable -- `sudo nano /etc/environment`
   adding the following line:
3. `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386`
4. Reboot, and Android Studio starts up.  (I had added also a link to studio.sh to the main menu).

Also I just found https://stackoverflow.com/a/17827697/2533809 which seems to have a nice write-up, pretty much the same answer.

(I'm using Debian 7 Wheezy)

Comment: For x64 JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64

Comment: if you dont have admin rights, you can also `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib...` as a command, or in your .$(shell)rc

Comment: You can also just logout and login instead of rebooting

Comment: Event with `JAVA_HOME` properly set, still the same error.

Comment: OK, I was misled by the JDK directory being there, while no JDK was installed (strange). I installed the JDK, and it's OK (just wonder why this JDK directory was there while there was no JDK).

Answer (score 10):

I have figured it out. You need to install openjdk-jdk. Opensjdk-jre is not enough. So in terminal all you need to do is write `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk` then press yes. Open the android studio bin folder, double click on studio.sh, open in terminal, press enter, and then android studio should work.

Comment: This works like a charm and is a lot less hassle than the other alternatives. Might not work for everyone,  but worth trying before editing a lot of files.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how I solved the same problem in my system:
Thanks for @user2533809

```
$sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
$ls /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386
ASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION  bin  docs  include  jre  lib  man  THIRD_PARTY_README
$export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386
$./studio.sh
```

**Environment :**

```
kesavan@kesavan-Ideapad-Z460:bin$ uname -a
Linux kesavan-Ideapad-Z460 3.2.0-59-generic-pae #0trisquel1 SMP Sat Feb 22 03:55:17 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
kesavan@kesavan-Ideapad-Z460:bin$
```

Answer (score 5):

You must be sure that your jre and jdk works fine.

Run

```
$ sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

and then...

```
$ sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

to make sure you have your javac path run

```
$ whereis javac
```

It should return something like this:

```
javac: /usr/bin/javac /usr/bin/X11/javac /usr/share/man/man1/javac.1.gz
```

If it does not work, you can try change the JAVA_HOME in /etc/enviroment file

Append JAVA_HOME="${/.../JVM_PATH}"

For example:

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64"
```

and then reload this file:

```
$ source /etc/environment
```

Source: [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-with-apt-get)

Answer (score 3):

This seems like permission problem. Someone who packed Android Studio, has the original files under non-root account. If you unpack it as root, the files and dirs has no permission for "other" (just for owner). The person who is packing Android Studio knows a lot about Android and Java, but not much about Unix permissions (uch!). There are two possible solutions:

a) unpack android-studio-bundle-...-linux.tgz as normal user, not as root (this has an advantage - you will be able to update Andriod Studio by clicking menu; but this is generally stupid because you are open to malware attack)

b) fix read permissions for files and dirs for whole android-studio directory with something like: chmod -R +r /opt/android-studio

Answer (score 2):

for openjdk:
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java

but you would better use the oracle jre to run android studio

Comment: and you should make sure already have package openjdk-7-jdk installed

Comment: It doesn't work.. export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64 .I get the same error

Comment: how can i set the java home to the oracle jre?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by installing the jdk.  This sounds annoyingly simple but I missed it.  I thought I Had installed the jdk, but I had actually installed the jre.

Wrong:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

Right:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

As soon as I did that, it started up fine for me.  The things we miss sometimes....

Answer (score 1):

Although I have JDK installed and was pointing to it, i didn't have java-1.7.0-openjdk-***devel*** installed (Fedora).

Comment: I am using Fedora 20 and this was my issue also.  Once I install the devel package and had my environment variable set, Android Studio fired right up!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to solve the problem:

cd /opt/    (where android-studio directory is located)

sudo chown -R your_user:your_user android-studio

(where **your_user** is... yes your username :) )

Answer (score 0):

the solution for me was to modify studio.sh and add JAVA_HOME as a variable:

```
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Locate a JDK installation directory which will be used to run the IDE.
# Try (in order): STUDIO_JDK, ../jre, JDK_HOME, JAVA_HOME, "java" in PATH.
# -------------------------------------------------------------------

     JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-i386/

if [ -n "$STUDIO_JDK" -a -x "$STUDIO_JDK/bin/java" ]; then (etc..)
```

Answer (score 0):

This below trick work for me , 
Check your app dependencies in  build.gradle(Project:AppName) .

Try the latest build.gradle version.

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'

Answer (score 0):

You have to have the latest JDK. I solved it by
   sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
(Note the '8' in there)